# What is the simplest way to get thread-safe property in Kotlin?

Tags: properties, thread-safety, kotlin

Is it the simplest way to get thread-safe property of Double type in Kotlin?

```
class SomeClass {
    @Volatile
    var someProp : Double? = null
        @Synchronized get
        @Synchronized set

}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of these you could save some typing by creating a delegate: https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/6r01v5/kotlin_and_property_thread_safety/dl1kelw/